# Django Translation in Overridden Form

Tags: python, django, forms, internationalization, lazy-evaluation

This is a problem with localisation:

I need to override the login form (base from the allauth library), to modify some formatting etc....

**forms.py**

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
class CustomLoginForm(LoginForm):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(CustomLoginForm ,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['login'].help_text    = _(u"Don't have an account? <a href='%(URL)s'>Register</a>" % {'URL':reverse('account_signup')})
        self.fields['password'].help_text = _(u"Forgotten Password? <a href='%(URL)s'>Reset</a>" % {'URL':reverse("account_reset_password")})
```

In the above, the translation is not being reflected in the form. I have made the necessary changed to the locale file **XYZ.po**, but it has no effect. All my other translations work fine, so clearly I am doing something wrong.

Here is the corresponding entry from **MYAPP/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po**

```
#: MYAPP/allauth/forms.py:16
#, python-format
msgid "Don't have an account? <a href='%(URL)s'>Register</a>"
msgstr "Ne pas avoir un compte? <a href='%(URL)s'>Enregistrer </a>"

#: MYAPP/allauth/forms.py:17
#, python-format
msgid "Forgotten Password? <a href='%(URL)s'>Reset</a>"
msgstr "Mot de passe oublié? <a href='%(URL)s'>Réinitialiser</a>"
```

Can someone steer me in the right direction please?

Cheers.

Comment: can you post the corresponding section in .po file

Comment: @AhmedHosny Yep, sure, see modification to question.

Comment: In cases like this I do recommend using ugettext_lazy with format as follows:
`_(u"Don't have account? <a href={URL}>Register</a>").format(URL=reverse('account_signup'))`. Try this and update me with the result

Comment: Ok, your suggestion works. There should be no 'quote marks', and it produces a slightly different decorator in the '.po' file, namely, `#, python-brace-format` If you would like to do an answer, ill check it off as a solution.

Comment: If you could explain why this formatting is required vs the other, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

`_(u"Don't have account? <a href={URL}>Register</a>").format(URL=reverse('account_signup'))`

Why `.format` works, actually I've searched for this before but I could not find a clear answer. My guess is:

1. Some symbols can make the translation fails such as % and single quote.
2. The translated string should use a placeholder which is satisfied in {} and %
3. There are guidlines here http://edx.readthedocs.org/projects/edx-developer-guide/en/latest/internationalization/i18n.html that I usually follow.